Why did Crimea’s parliament agree to join Ukraine in 1991?
I'm reading Medea Benjamin's War in Ukraine: Making Sense of a Senseless Conflict, which mentions that:

Crimea was transferred administratively from the
Russian Soviet Republic to the Ukrainian Soviet Republic
in 1954 after Nikita Khrushchev, who was from Ukraine,
succeeded the late Josef Stalin as Soviet leader.


After the Ukrainian parliament voted for independence from the Soviet Union in 1990, Crimea held
a referendum in January 1991; more than 94 percent of
its people voted for independence from Ukraine, and
Crimea briefly became an Autonomous Soviet Republic
within the U.S.S.R. But when the Soviet Union finally
broke up later that year, Crimea’s parliament agreed to
join Ukraine, overriding the expressed will of the large
majority of its people, until the issue came to the fore
again in 2014.

What were the circumstances that made Crimea’s parliament agree to join Ukraine although it was against the will of the majority  (questioning also if this was really the case) of the people?

Playing devil's advocate: it is not at all self-evident what "the will of the people" is if 94% voted to become a Republic of the USSR and just a couple of months later there is no more USSR.

@JörgWMittag That vote was also about joining the New Union of Soviet Sovereign Republics which didn't happen. I wonder which was the bigger driver, independence from Ukraine or joining the New Union (ie. not independent)? Maybe after the coup attitudes changed towards rejoining the Union and they figured they would be better off with Ukraine than independent.

There appears to be a lot of important information about the vote missing from this question.

@JörgWMittag: My immediate thought is an analogy to the U.K.'s referendum to keep Scotland in the U.K., followed by the U.K. referendum to leave the E.U. via Brexit. When that happened, there was a lot of speculation and expectation that Scotland would then demand another referendum to leave the U.K. again, on account of one of the arguments for staying being "The U.K. would not let you join the E.U.". I can't help but wonder if it's a similar thing here.

@JoeW That's why people ask questions.

Good question but maybe not answerable. Who knows what went on in the heads of the people there at this time. If they haven't said something or if they profited a lot personally, we can't really say.

Given the synopsis of the book, you should probably take what they write with a big spoonful of salt.

Not sure why you're ignoring the referendum from later that yeah in which Crimea voted to be part of an independent Ukraine: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1991_Ukrainian_independence_referendum

Note, also the authors of NATO: what you need to know and ... read from that book's own description of its authors to get a sense of their qualifications and sympathies.

Your comment is just an attempt to discredit the question. What matters is not the sympathies, but the facts that a book, may (or may not) bring forward to an independent mind. The sympathies do not change the facts (or absence thereof.) In fact, one can hardly hold an objective view by simply ignoring/dismissing any objections as unscientific/right-wing/pro-Russian/antisemitic/whatever. Only sources consistently furnishing counter-factual information can be dismissed... although even a broken clock shows correct time twice a day.

@JörgWMittag in the Crimean case the will of the current people also is a morally questionable standard, since the Soviet Union (Russia) engineered that  population to a huge degree.

@Wagthemainstreammediadog My comment is actually meant to be sympathetic to the question.  The OP likely got exactly this impression from this book and did not ask this question out of any bad faith, given this type of source material, just like an OP asking UN-related questions from John Bolton books might have received biased info.  As to your "your comment is just an attempt to discredit", I refer you kindly to this meta Q.

@ItalianPhilosopher in response to the meta question that you pointed out, the moderators set out a specific policy, so I am merely sticking to it. You seemed to agree with them at the time when the policy was set. So welcome to the western world, where rules equally apply to everyone,.

The quoted text and the Wikipage page you linked to do not seem to agree on the meaning of the referendum, and the book (and your question) are definitely wrong on "Crimea joining Ukraine" in 1991.
Wikipedia tells us:

The Crimean ASSR was originally created in 1921, as part of the Russian SFSR in the Soviet Union. Crimea was invaded by Nazi Germany during World War II, and when the region was reclaimed by the USSR in 1944, the Crimean Tatars and other ethnic groups were deported to Central Asia, and the ASSR was dissolved in 1945 with Crimea becoming an oblast of the Russian SSR. On 5 February 1954, it was transferred to the Ukrainian SSR. During the collapse of the Soviet Union at the start of the 1990s, the Russian SFSR declared itself sovereign on 12 June 1990 and the Ukrainian SSR declared itself sovereign on 16 July 1990.
In September 1990, the Soviet of People's Deputies of the Crimean Oblast called for the restoration of the Crimean Autonomous Soviet Socialist Republic together with the previous level of autonomy that the peninsula had enjoyed under the ASSR.

So they tell us:

1921 - WW II: Crimea was an ASSR within the Russian SFSR
WW II: invaded by Nazi Germany
1945 - 1954: Crimea was an Oblast in the Russian SSR
1954 - 1990: Crimea was an Oblast in the Ukrainian SSR

So the question is not whether they wanted to be part of Russia or of Ukraine or of any other SSR or altogether independent, but rather whether they wanted to remain an Oblast within an SSR, or become an ASSR within an SSR. Since they were already part of the Ukrainian SSR, that means switching from an Oblast in Ukraine to an ASSR within Ukraine. There's no mention of becoming independent from Ukraine, just gaining the "Autonomous" status within Ukraine (of course the ultimate goal could have been independence, but that was not what was explicitly expressed at this point).
And so that's what the Ukrainian (not Crimean) parliament (reluctantly, apparently) did after the referendum: exactly what the people voted for.
The Crimean Parliament later "declared the state sovereignty of Crimea as a constituent part of Ukraine". But that's not "joining Ukraine" (they were already part of Ukraine for decades), that's just going one notch further in their autonomy (normally declaring state sovereignty would be a claim for independence, but they still decided to remain "a constituent part of Ukraine).
The book makes it appear as a referendum on independence, when it definitely wasn't (it was a move in that direction, sure, but it wasn't independence). Autonomy and independence are quite different things (ask Catalonia or Scotland).
I hope the rest of the book is better, but given the synopsis...

Pro-russian is a stretch. The Russian language doesn't have definite articles so it definitely didn't originate there.

@uberhaxed Not sure, but I think they mean that "The Ukraine" makes it sound like a region, like 'The Alps', and thus not a country?

@ToddWilcox Some of the "the Ukraine" come from quotes, and I wondered why there's this weird usage, but it's not a unique case (The Gambia, The Bahamas, the Philippines, the United Kingdom, the Netherlands...), and I've seen it so often I reproduced it without thing more about it, but I realise that it is indeed now considered bad form in the case of Ukraine. Fixed.

@jcaron it is said that "the Ukraine" is an old preferred usage but now the article gets dropped. It is similar how the Ukrainians want Russian speakers say "в Украине" instead of "На Украине". The later makes impression that Ukraine is a noun meaning "the outskirts".

Autonomous_Soviet_Socialist_Republics (ASSRs) belong to Soviet Republics (SSRs). There is no precedent that I know of that an ASSR would be a top-level entity within USSR.
So what they've voted in is becoming an ASSR within Ukrainian SSR, which turned into the Autonomous Republic of Crimea inside Ukraine.
I don't see any way there to treat Crimea as ASSR inside Russian Soviet Federative Socialist Republic (RSFSR, e.g. Russia) in context of this referendum, even though that's where it was before WWII I also don't see any ASSRs becoming independent states, even though one of the  USSR decrees would permit it.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

That 1990 law is written with so much vage language! Not surprising, it lead to wars in Chechnya and in other places. By the way, this add some potential legitimacy to Russian claims in Crimea, despite Russians did not cite that law.

This law shows how legal skills degraded by the end of the USSR: they could not even formulate laws in precise language.

The 1991 referendum was definitely an independence referendum. As the Wikipedia article on it says:

The referendum did not just call for the restoration for the ASSR, but
further called for Crimea to be a participant in the New Union Treaty
– an ultimately futile attempt by Mikhail Gorbachev to reconstitute
the USSR. This would have meant that Crimea would have been a
sovereign subject of the renewed USSR[10] and separate from the
Ukrainian SSR (emphasis mine).

Crimeans plans were to establish themselves as an independent, sovereign state, and they chose the path of least resistance they saw: becoming an ASSR, joining the New Union Treaty and establish their independence. The fall of the Soviet Union before the New Union Treaty could materialize left them in a limbo, caught in the step 1 of the process - becoming an ASSR - without a way to make it into step 2.
With the fall of the Soviet Union later that year, Ukraine accepted Crimea's new name, but not its status. So Crimea could call itself "autonomous", but it wasn't. Ukraine called a referendum to declare itself independent, but approval was low in Crimea. In May 1992, Crimea's parliament then declared independence from Ukraine, but Kiev's authority called that decision illegal. Again, Crimea's parliament decided to postpone the referendum that should ratificate the decision - but they didn't cancel it.
In 1994, they ran another referendum of independence, and this time they went ahead despite Ukraine's wishes - Ukraine was suffering the economic collapse of all ex-soviet republics, and had been stripped of its nuclear weapons, so they probably thought they couldn't afford a military operation. The 1994 referendum asked for Crimeans to have dual ukrainian/russian citizenship, President of Crimea's decrees having status of law and relationship between Crimea and Ukraine to be defined in a Treaty - so, de facto independence, even if Ukraine wanted to keep considering Crimea as part of Ukraine. The three questions were aproved by solid majorities - even if the USSR didn't exist anymore.
The situation deteriorated rapidly, with Crimean authorities creating state agencies and infrastructures as if they were actually sovereign, until Ukraine sent the army in.

The situation became so threatening that the Ukrainian authorities
were forced to take decisive measures to restore Ukrainian sovereignty
on the peninsula. In March 1995, the Ukrainian Parliament abolished
the Crimean Constitution and the office of the President of Crimea.
Soldiers of the National Guard of Ukraine and Ukrainian special forces
were transferred to the peninsula.

All in all, Crimea staying in Ukraine despite wanting to be independent is not different from Ukraine voting that ukrainian laws have precedence over soviet laws, but not outright declaring independence back in 1990. Declaring independence of a part of the country is usually met by a military response from the central government - it's not just that a powerful USRR would sent its tanks to Prague, it's that UK sent its army against Washington, and Lincoln sent the Union Army against the Confederates. When you're dealing with independence, cautious steps are sensible options. Ukraine only declared itself independent after the definitive collapse of the USSR, while Crimea's attempts of independence in 1991 and 1994 were ignored or crushed, and only the one in 2014 - with russian troops on the territory - went ahead.

Any source about "Ukrainian authorities [not liking] this referendum" or about "Ukranian tanks warming engines" ?

@Evargalo Removed the more colorful language and added more references. ;)

This part of history is somewhat hypocritically ignored by Ukraine, just like Kosovos status is hypocritically seen as being any different from the status of other former Yugoslav nations. In the end Right is Might, as proven both by the 1994 tanks rolling into Crimea from Ukraine and 2014 from Russia.

@JonathanReez I think you wanted to say 'Might is Right', but yeah, I agree. ;)

+1 No doubt it's hard to make a convincing argument that Crimeans were (are?) massively pro-Ukraine, which is why I upvoted this Q.  On the other hand, supposedly the 2014 pro-Russia independence referendum - very highly supported according to Moscow - supposedly had fairly low numbers and participation, according to results allegedly mistakenly posted by one of Russia's electoral watchdog agencies.  The 2 could even coexist:  ethnic Russians wanting to stay with Russia in the 90s.  And disenchanted with the prospects of joining it in 2014, after seeing 25 years of post-Soviet authoritarianism

@ItalianPhilosopher Oh, absolutely. I thought of adding some lines clarifying that Crimeans' objective was full independence, NOT BECOMING PART OF RUSSIA, but I didn't found sources that could substantiate this claim, although I think it's self-evident. Crimeans didn't want to become russians, even if 60% of the population is of russian origin. But it happens that might is right, as JonathanReez was pointing out, and the first referendums were ignored by Kiev, and the last one which succeeded was guided by Russia, so Crimea has never been allowed to self-determinate.

@ItalianPhilosopher I mean, Crimeans didn't want to be russians even in the 90s. The geographical isolation and multi-ethnic and multicultural composition of the population gives them a fairly disctinctive culture from mainland russians. Just like different Spanish-speaking countries in Latin America may feel about each other, they may feel some affinity for Russia but they don't see themselves as russian. But full independence was never a posibility.

There are some misleading inaccuracies here. Apparently you use the words "autonomy", "sovereignty" and "independence"  synonymously, but in context they define more specific relations. Like autonomy is seems to be a form of self-governance within the constitutional guidelines of a superstructure. While sovereignty is the ability to make laws in contradiction with the super structure, so Ukraine and Russia claimed sovereignty before claiming independence from the USSR. Likewise Crimea has requested autonomy and having that granted, unilaterally declared sovereignty and got that contested.

2/ But what I can't find is that they actually declared or requested independence anywhere. Sure the ASSR request had a provision of joining the new Soviet Union as an independent member state, but that is practically ditching one dependence for another. After that failed they continuously demanded and declared a status of "Sovereignty WITHIN Ukraine". So something like Ukraine's status in the USSR post-1990, not bound by law but still in a Union. That's also the wording of the 1994 referendum. Because it's likely that independence meant annexation, but sovereignty meant privileged existence.

The other two answer already hint at that but maybe one should mention the distinction explicitly:
Apparently the Union of Soviet Socialist Republics (USSR) is a union of Soviet Socialist Republics (SSR), which were prior to joining the union independent socialist countries that organized in the form of soviet republic. While an Autonomous Soviet Socialist Republic (ASSR) is somewhere below a Union Republic, but above an autonomous oblasts and the autonomous okrugs.
So as Alamar has mentioned those are not top-level members of the USSR, but rather nations wihin one of the existing SSRs. What cultural, administrative and political autonomies that actually entailed could vary drastically depending on the era. One important feature of that "autonomous" part however is that these regions can not leave the union on their own, but only as part of their host country. Though if they wish to remain after the independence of their host country they could chose to do that.
Also Crimea's status and history as a region, country, nation and whatnot has changed quite a bit over time. Like ignoring the early history, the Kievan Rus, the Mongol conquest, a Crimean Tatar state that apparently lasted more than 300 years before it was conquered by the Ottoman Empire. The Russian Empire beaten the Ottoman Empire and it became a politically independent Tatar state again but as Russia wanted that Black Sea access they were annexed shortly after. Then the revolution happened and Crimea's status changed wildly:

Crimean People's Republic     December 1917 – January 1918    Crimean Tatar government
Taurida Soviet Socialist Republic     19 March – 30 April 1918    Bolshevik government
Ukrainian State   May – June 1918
First Crimean Regional Government     25 June – 25 November 1918  German puppet state under Lipka Tatar General Maciej (Suleyman) Sulkiewicz
Second Crimean Regional Government    November 1918 – April 1919  Anti-Bolshevik government under Crimean Karaite former Kadet member Solomon Krym
Crimean Socialist Soviet Republic     2 April – June 1919     Bolshevik government
South Russian Government  February – April 1920   Government of White movement's General Anton Denikin
Government of South Russia    April (officially, 16 August) – 16 November 1920    Government of White movement's General Pyotr Wrangel
Bolshevik revolutionary committee government  November 1920 – 18 October 1921     Bolshevik government under Béla Kun (until 20 February 1921), then Mikhail Poliakov
Crimean Autonomous Socialist Soviet Republic  18 October 1921 – 30 June 1945  Autonomous republic of the Russian SFSR

Then it was conquered by the Nazis in WWII and after the Soviet Union regained control over the territory they deported the Tartars elsewhere within the USSR so that they can demote Crimea from an ASSR to an oblast within the Russian Soviet Federative Socialist Republic (RSFSR). Which then was in 1954 was transferred to the Ukrainian SSR on the 300th anniversary of a union of Russia and Ukraine:

The territory had been recognized within the Soviet Union as having "close ties" to the Ukrainian SSR, and the transfer commemorated the Union of Russia and Ukraine Tercentenary. Wiki

Also apparently Stalin's successor Nikita Khrushchev was from Ukraine. And it remained an Oblast of Ukraine until 1991. However when the RSFSR and the Ukrainian SSR left the Union, the Crimean Oblast asked for the restoration of it's ASSR status which is the subject of that referendum and also for a Union Republic status within the New Union Treaty. Which, if it would have that had come to exist, would have meant that Crimea would have been an independent country separate from Ukraine.
So Crimea didn't so much join Ukraine but remained within Ukraine. Also that's too simplistic as well. As the Crimean ASSR then transformed into the Republic of Crimea, which actually declare it's independence as a sovereign country, but a day later specified for that state to be in a union between Crimea and Ukraine as basically a federation of 2. Scheduling a referendum which Ukraine was not too fond of and which never actually happened and so they struggled for some years to figure out their exact status and relation to each other.
With apparently a noteworthy encounter in 1995 when a pro-Russian president was elected in Crimea who received a boost from a referendum for more autonomy, yet who managed to run into conflict with the Crimean parliament, who then downgraded him from head of state to head of the executive branch, upon which that president disbanded parliament and apparently attempting a power grab. Upon which Ukraine intervened, appointed a new president, abolished the constitution and the laws in conflict with the Ukrainian constitution, downgraded the status of Crimea and put the former president on a plane to Moscow.
And after period of full control by Kyiv Crimea again became an Autonomous Republic and got a new constitution in 1998.
Meanwhile after the fall of the Soviet Union, Russia decided that the 1954 transfer was a mistake and also wanted Crimea back though that apparently was settled for some time with a special status for the city of Sevastopol and the Black Sea Fleet and affirmed the lack of a claim of Crimea and the territorial integrity of Ukraine (including Crimea) in the Budapest Memorandum of 1994.
So yeah the relation of Crimea, Russia and Ukraine and it's status as independent, associated, incorporated, dependent, occupied, self-governed and whatnot is quite complicated. Though with all the quests for independence and autonomy it's quite odd that within Russia, Crimea currently doesn't even have the status of an Oblast anymore but was downgraded to a part of the southern district.

Many of SSRs did not have statehood prior to being carved out of RSFSR, or only had it for a fleeting amount of time.

@alamar The other way around the Russian Empire and later on the RSFSR had incorporated and conquered lots of places and thus removed their existence as sovereign states. So it's usually not that they had made up states because the list of 4 Union members was too short, but that these places already had some sort of ethnic history and a statehood status that switched in and out of existence. Also where carved out from the RSFSR we're not talking 1990 but rather early Soviet Union or before.

They sure had some ethnic basis but more often than not, there were never an independent state with the borders resembling a newly created SSR.

@alamar Which ones do you mean in particular? Like the first 4(-6) had, so Russia, Ukraine, Byelorussia and  Armenia, Azerbaijan, and Georgia which from the Transcaucasian federation. As did the 3 Baltic states. Moldova also had declared independence. Uzbekistan seems to be new, while it's subsidiary Tajikistan seems to have more of a history. While Turkmenistan seemed to have been a region but not a state. Now Kazakhstan and Kyrgyzstan are new and quite confusing, as the latter was the new state of the Kazakhs while Russians though that sounds to close to Cossacks, but...

which was nonetheless renamed later, while a different part of Turkmenistan than became Kyrgyzstan... Anyway at that point the majority of SSRs either had statehood or regional borders and the ones formed later were divisions of SSRs not actually formed from the RSFSR actually with very few exceptions. Also with regards to solid borders, I think many European nations including Russia itself would struggle with that requirement.

Transcaucasian statehood is very new. There were provinces of Russian Empire with non-ethnic borders, before that non-consolidated principalities. The idea of their division based on ethnic distribution was new. Belarus didn't have any meaningful statehood prior. Ukraine barely had.

@alamar From what I can find, after the dissolution of the Russian Empire, a short lived Transcaucasian Democratic Federative Republic seceded and formed it's own country in 1918. It didn't last particularly long before it fell apart as the states of Georgia,  Armenia and Azerbaijan declared their independence. They were subsequently invaded and sovietized forming the respective SSRs which were regrouped into the TSFSR which then again fell apart into it's constituting SSRs which got elevated to full membership. So not actually new and artificial.

That depends on the interpretation, because I would call exactly this order of events "only fleeting prior statehood".

@alamar Which is nonetheless a statehood. Which is in so far noteworthy as this is not a case of "the lord/Russia giveth and the lord taketh", but rather that you already had organized ethnic groups, that often had already laid claim on particular borders. So that's less of "was carved from the RSFSR" but rather an acceptance of a prior reality under a new status. Likely given that if they hadn't granted these rights to an semi-independent state, they'd have a continuation of the civil war for decades to come, while so they'd have an ally where the control can be increased incrementally.

@alamar The other obvious truth is that "new" or not, we're speaking of "new" at the time anyway, by now these states exist for up to over 100 years by now even the younger ones existing for 60+ years. So there are already people who lived the entirety of their lives in those existing borders and social groups and just ignoring those realities because of legal shenanigans either way is likely not going to work peacefully.

Nobody denies that now they have significant history of statehood.

@alamar Vladimir P.?

I think he got a reality check.
